# Unable to access static const variable declared outside the class

Tags: c++, variables, static, segmentation-fault, constants

I have declared a **static const variable** before the **ConfigureManager.h** class declaration like this:

```
static const std::string CONFIGURE_FILE_PATH = "./abc.conf";
class ConfigureManager: private boost::noncopyable
{
...
};
```

Later on when I am trying to access it from **ConfigureManager.cpp** class methods, it is giving me segmentation fault error.

```
#include "ConfigureManager.h"
void ConfigureManager::xyz()
{   
    std::cout << "configureFilePath " << CONFIGURE_FILE_PATH << std::endl;
}
```

I am using g++ compiler in ubuntu environment.

Comment: the problem is somewhere else in the code.

Comment: is `xyz` called during static initialization before main?

Answer (score 0):

I had no issues inserting, compiling, and running your code.  The string was sent to the console.  Post the error message or more code...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of g++ your using, but is there any reason you don't define it as a static const char* in the header and then define it to "./abc.conf" in the cpp?

If it's c++11 you may be able to use an initalizer list to define it as well in the header- specifically.
    static const std::string CONFIGURE_FILE_PATH = {"./abc.conf"};